# ItemResolvers not working as expected

Tags: mvc, pipelines

Using Sitecore 8.1

I have two custom ItemResolvers in my site, in this order:

- `ItemResolver` (The sitecore default)
- `ProductItemResolver` (Determines if a product exists for a wildcard item)
- `NotFoundItemResolver` (Sets a default item, if no item has been set)

The code is as follows:

ProductItemResolver.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Based on https://superruub.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/sitecore-wildcard-404-page/
/// </summary>
public class ProductItemResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        Profiler.StartOperation("Resolve product item");
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
        if (((Context.Item != null && Context.Item.Name == "*") && (Context.Database != null))
            && (args.Url.ItemPath.Length != 0)
            && Context.Item.TemplateID == SitecoreConstants.Templates.Product.Id)
        {
            //Fetch product from elastic
            var productId = args.Context.Request.Url.GetProductId();
            var catalogService = ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve<ICatalogService>();
            var productExists = catalogService.ProductExists(productId);

            //If it is null, set Context.Item to null to trigger NotFound flow
            if (!productExists)
            {
                Context.Item = null;
            }
        }
        Profiler.EndOperation();
    }
}
```

NotFoundItemResolver:

```
/// <summary>
/// Based on https://laubplusco.net/handling-404-sitecore-avoid-302-redirects/
/// </summary>
public class NotFoundItemResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        //Check if we even need to hande this
        if (IsValidContextItemResolved()
            || args.LocalPath.StartsWith("/sitecore")
            || args.Url.FilePath.StartsWith("/sitecore")
            || RequestIsForPhysicalFile(args.Url.FilePath))
            return;

        var siteSettingsProvider = ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve<ISiteSettingsProvider>();
        ISiteSettings siteSettings = siteSettingsProvider.Get();

        if (siteSettings.NotFoundItem == null
            || siteSettings.NotFoundItem.Empty
            || !siteSettings.NotFoundItem.HasContextLanguage())
            return;

        Context.Item = siteSettings.NotFoundItem;
    }

    protected virtual bool IsValidContextItemResolved()
    {
        if (Context.Item == null || !Context.Item.HasContextLanguage())
            return false;
        return !(Context.Item.Visualization.Layout == null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebUtil.GetQueryString("sc_layout")));
    }

    protected virtual bool RequestIsForPhysicalFile(string filePath)
    {
        return File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath));
    }
}
```

The NotFound item has a controller configured on the standardvalues of its template.

```
public class NotFoundController : BaseController
{
    // GET
    public override ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return View("~/Views/Shared/Core/NotFound.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Now, if I hit a url where sitecore does not find an item, I get what I expect. I hit my NotFound controller, and render my NotFound view.

But if Sitecore resolves the wildcard item, and I set the `Context.Item = null` in the ProductItemResolver, then I get the layout from the wildcard item rendered, and the `Context.Item.Name` in the .cshtml file returns "*". Even though I just changed the item.

But the http status code of the response is 404.

What is going on here? Am I hitting some sort of caching issue?

Comment: I would suggest to check the order in which the pipelines are getting called. It looks like Sitecore ItemResolver is being called , when it shouldnt

Comment: MVC resolves it (again). Ref: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/sitecore-mvc-context-item/

Comment: @MarkCassidy I think you hit it right on the money. But I think that I will change my NotFound page approach to move away from the MVC pipeline. This is the only scenario where I was using it, and probably makes sense to align with the rest of the site. 

If you would add your commen as an answer, I will mark that as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sitecore MVC resolves it (again)

Which is both confusing and (I find) a little odd. But here's what's happening.

You patch after the regular `ItemResolver` and do your custom work. And you assume all is well from that point on. And normally it would be.

But Sitecore MVC adds a series of steps to the pipeline (for MVC requests, obviously), one of them being an execution of the `mvc.getPageItem` pipeline to build up the MVC-specific context class `Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext`.

And `mvc.getPageItem` (you probably guessed it), sets a new value in `Sitecore.Context.Page`.

To work around this behaviour, one of the easiest approaches is to indicate (on `HttpContext.Items` for instance) that your processor has done work, and then check for this value at the end of the `mvc.GetPageItem` processor.

For previous and current Sitecore versions, @JammyKam has a full write up on his blog:

- [Resolving Custom Context.Item in Sitecore MVC](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/sitecore-mvc-context-item/)