# Sitecore Wildcards overwrites existing page items

Tags: wildcards

Sitecore version: 9.0
Using SXA

I have inherted a project that uses a wildcard item will try to render a route that will get pass through.

So for my example I am rendering blog articles.

So `/blog/{blog-article}` will render an article that my wildcard will picked up. This is all working correctly

Under blog item there are also some page item which are used to show blog posts by category, So `/blog/culture` doesn’t get picked up by the wildcard and will instead render the page.

However when a new page item is added, it doesn’t seem to recognise the page and instead default to the wildcard. Is there some route exception or something that needs to be populated so the wildcard will ignore certain routes? I can’t see anything obvious in Sitecore or our codebase and I've crawled through the documentation with no luck.

Wondering if there is any additional setup I could be missing.

The wildcard is currently at the top of the directory on both master and web databases

Comment: What is the order or items in Sitecore tree? Is "culture" above "*" item? And your new page, is it also above it?

Comment: Move the wildcard to the highest sort order. (after all the items you DO want to catch)

Answer (score 1):

My issue was to do with ItemResolvers in the end

I followed the solution mentioned on https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/7698/7403

> Sitecore MVC resolves it (again) Which is both confusing and (I find)
> a little odd. But here's what's happening.
>
> You patch after the regular ItemResolver and do your custom work. And
> you assume all is well from that point on. And normally it would be.
>
> But Sitecore MVC adds a series of steps to the pipeline (for MVC
> requests, obviously), one of them being an execution of the
> mvc.getPageItem pipeline to build up the MVC-specific context class
> Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.
>
> And mvc.getPageItem (you probably guessed it), sets a new value in
> Sitecore.Context.Page.
>
> To work around this behaviour, one of the easiest approaches is to
> indicate (on HttpContext.Items for instance) that your processor has
> done work, and then check for this value at the end of the
> mvc.GetPageItem processor.
>
> For previous and current Sitecore versions, @JammyKam has a full write
> up on his blog:
>
> [Resolving Custom Context.Item in Sitecore MVC](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/08/02/sitecore-mvc-context-item/)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above functionality you can perform the below steps:

1. In a normal scenario, we create a page for each product listed under
   the `Global/Products` folder in your case it's `/blog/{blog-article}`
   and presentation details having the rendering with the respective
   product data source. But here we will not assign any data source
   into the rendering to display the product information, now the
   question is how information of the product will be displayed or how
   will you assign the data source? The answer is dynamic, we will
   assign the data source to the rendering. As we are aware that
   the rendering depends on the
   RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource and instead of
   assigning the data source in presentation details rendering we will
   assign it dynamically.
2. To achieve this you need to write one pipeline `mvc.getRenderer` and
   assign the data source runtime by overriding the process method of
   the pipeline based on the URL requested. So once the user will hit
   the All products page URL with the product code or name, we will get
   that product item from the Global/Products folder and assign it to
   the rendering data source, if it does not found then we will
   redirect it to the 404 pages.
3. In the configuration file, we will define the rendering name as
   well, so in the process method, we can identify the name of the
   rendering. My rendering name is ProductDetail. Here my configuration
   path file:

```
  <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <mvc.getRenderer>
        <processor type="Helixbase.Feature.Products.Pipelines.WildcardDatasource, Helixbase.Feature.Products"                  patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.GetViewRenderer, Sitecore.Mvc']">
          <renderingname>ProductsDetail</renderingname>
        </processor>
      </mvc.getRenderer>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

4. In the process method, first, we will get the rendering name and
   check that The rendered page name is `*` and the applied rendering
   name is the same as we defined into the configuration file then only
   we will be procced. After that, we will get the product code or name
   from the Request URL segment and find the item with the same name or
   code into the product list i.e. `Global/Product` folder. Finally, we
   will assign that item to the rendering data source. Code for the
   configuration patch file:

```
namespace Helixbase.Feature.Products.Pipelines
{
    public class WildCardDataSource : GetRendererProcessor
    {
        private string RenderingName { get; set; }
        public override void Process(GetRendererArgs args)
        {
            var productsDetailRendering = RenderingName;
            if (args.PageContext.Item.Name != "*" 
                || !args.Rendering.RenderingItem.Name.Equals(productsDetailRendering, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return;

            if (args.PageContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url == null) return;

            const string datasourceFolder = "/sitecore/content/Helixbase/Global/Products";
            var dataSourcePath =
                $"{datasourceFolder}/{args.PageContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Segments.Last()}";

            var dataSourceItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dataSourcePath);
            if (dataSourceItem != null)
            {
                args.Rendering.DataSource = dataSourcePath;
            }
            else
            {
                // 404 page not found
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your case, you can handle the `culture` item into the process method and perform the operation as per your requirement.

See the blog post: [Wildcard Item in Sitecore](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/06/wildcard-item-in-sitecore.html)

Comment: Hi - the wild card is setup, that is not my issue. Its the fact that new pages items that sit in the directory the wildcard sits under are not rendering. However existing page items are